# QDir.setNameFilter how to show only files with specific extensions?

Tags: c++, qt, filter, qdir

setNameFilters isn't working as I would expect, so if anyone can explain if I'm using it incorrectly, or if maybe this is a bug in Qt:

Here is my code sample:

```
QDir export_folder("C:\path");
QStringList fileList = export_folder.setNameFilters(QStringList()<<"*.exe");
```

after processing fileList contains the String "test.exe1"

I would expect fileList to only include files with extension .exe NOT .exe*.

If I wanted file extensions longer than .exe I would expect to put in `"*.exe*"` as my filter.

Can someone help clarify, or do I manually have to process my fileList after the fact?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For starters, `setNameFilters` does not return `QStringList`, it returns nothing. Your code should look like this:

```
QDir export_folder("C:\\path");
export_folder.setNameFilters(QStringList()<<"*.exe");
QStringList fileList = export_folder.entryList();
```

Filtering works as expected (not returning files ending with "exe2") in Linux with Qt 5.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you want to show files with more than one kind of extensions, you can do like the following.

```
export_folder.setNameFilters( QStringList() << "*.exe" << "*.pdf" << "*.docx" << "*.jpg" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export_folder.setNameFilters(QStringList {"*.exe1 *.exe2 *.exe3", "EXE1 (*.exe1)", "EXE23 (*.exe2 *.exe3)"});
```